# Remove starting content from each line of file

Tags: powershell

I need to remove the time stamp details from each line which is present at the start. How can I achieve?

I tried to use

```
regex = "[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,4} [0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]
{1,2}):[0-9]{1,3}"
```

and my approach was like

```
$Check = (Get-Content -Path .\file.txt|Select-Object -last 3|Out-String)         

$Check = $Check -replace('$regex','')
```

The lines in text file.txt would be like :

```
[06/13/19 08:52:58] The new world 

[06/13/19 08:52:58] Computing 

[06/13/19 08:52:58] Technology
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if it is a static stamp just use substring.

```
$start = Get-Content -Path C:\Windows\Panther\setupact.log -First 1
$start.Substring(11,8)
```

This for example only extracs the timestamp.

in your case:

```
$start = "[06/13/19 08:52:58] Technology"
$start.Substring(20)
```

this removes it.

Hope it helps! BR

Edit (see comment):

```
$content = Get-Content .\Desktop\test.txt

$newLine = ""
foreach($line in $content){
    if($line.IndexOf("[") -eq 0){
        $newLine += $line.Substring(20) + " "
        $prev = $true
    }
    else{
        if($line -ne ""){
            Write-Host $newLine
            $newLine = ""
        }

        write-host $line
        $prev = $false
    }
}
```

Comment: @A guest who's called Redd, its not static time stamp

Comment: So there are lines with stamp and whithout stamp? or does size change?

Comment: Yes.Size doesn't change. But there are lines without time stamp if its likt that i need to concat with the line having timestamp. Like in the example of line mentioned above after removing the timestamp i need to club all lines into single line

Comment: Hidei the edit should do as you wanted to have it like. Please test it and give me feedback if it works. BR

Comment: @A guest who's called Redd, Thanks your solution works

Answer (score 2):

and alternate method would be to use the `-split` string operator and split on `]` [that is close-bracket & space]. something like this ...

```
('[06/13/19 08:52:58] The new world' -split '] ')[1].Trim()
```

output = `The new world`